# Populate Textbox with Checkbox Value in classic ASP and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp-classic

here is a snippet of my code:

```
 response.write "<th align=left><font size=2>"
    response.write "1. <input type=checkbox class='checkboxes' value='ORG'>Organization"
    response.write "</font> </th>"
    response.write "<th align=left><font size=2>"
    response.write "2. <input type=checkbox  value='OpType' class='checkboxes'>Operation Type"
    response.write "</font> </th>"
    response.write "<th align=left><font size=2>"
    response.write "3. <input type=checkbox checked  value='YEAR' class='checkboxes'>Year"
    response.write "</font> </th>"

response.write "<tr><td colspan='3'> <input name='DISTRIBUTION' size='45' /></td></tr>"
```

here is the javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
$('.checkboxes').change(function () {
    alert("1");
    $("input[Title='DISTRIBUTION']").val("");
    if ($('.checkboxes').is(':checked')) {
        $("input[Title='DISTRIBUTION']").val("Yes");
    }
});
```

i am not seeing the alert, so it does not look like it gets fired. did i do something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the script is being executed before the document is fully constructed? Just a guess, but try wrapping your jquery code within this;

```
$(document).ready(function () { ... });
```

You should also look into KnockoutJs - it'll make your life easier...

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is simply a case of not waiting till the DOM is ready before assigning the event handlers.  Try this instead...

```
$(function() {
    $('.checkboxes').change(function () {
        alert("1");
        $("input[Title='DISTRIBUTION']").val("");
        if ($('.checkboxes').is(':checked')) {
            $("input[Title='DISTRIBUTION']").val("Yes");
        }
    });
});
```